# Invalid operand to binary expression on std::max_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, operator-overloading

I'm trying to use std::max_element to find the largest element in a std::forward_list of a defined structure. Here is the code below:

```
//.h file:
#include <unordered_map>
#include <forward_list>

// my structure: 
struct A
{
    uint8_t length;
    bool reverseMatch;

    bool operator<(const A& rhs);
    A() : length(0), reverseMatch(false) {}
};

using Alias = std::unordered_map<uint32_t, std::forward_list<A>>;

class B
{
    Alias data;

public:
    parse(string inputFilename);
    A getBestMatch(uint32_t lineNumber);
};
```

Troublesome function:

```
//.cpp file
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include "file.h"

bool A::operator<(const A& rhs)
{
    return (this->length < rhs.length);
}
A B::getBestMatch(uint32_t lineNumber)
{
    A ret;
    auto dataIter = this->data.find(lineNumber);
    if (dataIter != data.end())
    {
        ret = *(std::max_element(dataIter->second.begin(), dataIter->second.end()));//!!!ERROR!!!
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The error that I'm getting is "Invalid operands to binary expression ('const A' and 'const A')". I'm not sure why my operator< overload is having issues here. Do I need to define other operands as well? If so, why? All documentation that I have read states that std::max_element uses the < operator. Thanks!

Comment: Make `operator<` const, as in `bool operator<(const A& rhs) const;` As written, you allow the right hand side to be const - but not the left hand side.

Comment: I see. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem with `std::sort`, it was particularly difficult to solve because gcc didn't detect it, and llvm error is cryptic.
A minimal example to reproduce the error: https://rextester.com/TPDK32644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed to

```
bool operator<(const A& rhs) const;
```

as Igor stated above and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `operator<` is non-const, but even better would be to make it a non-member, which has the side effect of making the left and right arguments consistent:

```
bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs)
{
    return (lhs.length < rhs.length);
}
```

You can declare it in your header, outside the class, like this:

```
bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs);
```

Some people (myself included) prefer to keep such functions outside the class when they do not require private access.