# Invalid operands to binary expression error (missing const) in std::sort: Why does specifying the compare operator solve it?

Tags: c++, sorting, gcc, clang, operator-overloading

Considering:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    double dummy;
    
    bool operator<(const A& a) { ///Here I am missing a `const`
        return dummy < a.dummy;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a;
    a.push_back({0.9});
    a.push_back({0.4});
    std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine on gcc, but on clang it gives

```
/usr/include/c++/v1/algorithm:719:71: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const A' and 'const A')
    bool operator()(const _T1& __x, const _T1& __y) const {return __x < __y;}
```

and a long list of failed instantiation.
Here is my minimal example in action: https://rextester.com/VEO17629

I could finally solve it when I found [Invalid operand to binary expression on std::max_element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833967/invalid-operand-to-binary-expression-on-stdmax-element) (the `operator <` must have a `const` specifier).

The curious thing is that the error goes away also if I call `std::sort` specifying the operator `std::less<>()`:

```
std::sort(a.begin(),a.end(),std::less<>());
```

**Why does specifying the compare operator `std::less<>()` solve the error?**

Comment: Well godbolt clang implementation does not produce the same error, (and I cycled through some versions and also used c++11) https://godbolt.org/z/sbjhnr68Y

Comment: @anastaciu It will if you [use `libc++`](https://godbolt.org/z/Yqn4z5hzz)

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, it appears so, anyway you did answer the asked question in conclusive manner, let's see if the OP has follow up, still, I'd think you'd have more votes 2 hours passed... These people... 

Comment: @anastaciu I had a swim in the different versions of the standard to see what I could dig up. To me it seems like both behaviors are allowed up until C++17, but since C++20, `std::less{}` _should_ be used in the `std::sort(a.begin(),a.end());` case, so right now that seems to be a bug in `libc++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does specifying the compare operator `std::less<>()` solve the error?

Interestingly enough, it's only when you use [`std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) (`std::less<>`) that it compiles. `std::less<A>` does not.

`std::less<A>::operator()`:

```
constexpr bool operator()( const T& lhs, const T& rhs ) const;
```

The `std::less<void>::operator()` has a slightly different signature, not specifying `const T&`:

```
template< class T, class U>
constexpr auto operator()( T&& lhs, U&& rhs ) const
  -> decltype(std::forward<T>(lhs) < std::forward<U>(rhs));
```

So, the `std::less<void>::operator()` is free to call the non-`const` `operator<`.

---

The difference between `g++` (`libstdc++`) and `clang++` (`libc++`) can have some different explanations. One would be if `libstdc++` forwards  `std::sort(a.begin(),a.end())` to `std::sort(a.begin(),a.end(), std::less<>{})` instead of using `operator<` directly.

In C++14 (that you used in your demo) [`[alg.sorting]/1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/alg.sorting#1) just says: "*All the operations in 25.4 have two versions: one that takes a function object of type `Compare` and one that uses an `operator<`.*".

There is nothing prohibiting using `std::less<void>` to call `operator<`.

In C++20
[`[sort]/1`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/sort#1) there has even been an addition, specifying exactly that behavior when no comparator is given:
"***Let `comp` be `less{}`** and `proj` be `identity{}` for the overloads with no parameters by those names.*". `clang++`/`libc++` in C++20 mode fails to comply to this though.

Comment: Very thorough explanation, thank you! I wonder why they didn't force constness of parameters for `std::less<void>::operator()`!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure why they left the non-`const` backdoor open. Perhaps there is some use case where comparing objects and letting them mutate is ok. Hmm... (and thanks for fixing my typo btw)